# How to select a class of an id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, logic

I have two div with different id but same class how do I select a class of a given id ?

```js
$(function() {
      $('#1').find('.select').click(function() {

        alert("1 clicked ");

      });
      $("#2 .select").click(function() {

        alert("2 clicked ");

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
    <button class="select">one</button>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <button class="select">two</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("select");`

Comment: Your fiddle is far to be a working example of the code posted here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first Div is missing a Closing div tag.Please correct that.

So:-

```
<div id="1">
  <button class="select">one</button>
 <div>
```

Needs to be:-

```
<div id="1">
  <button class="select">one</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Such suggestions should be posted as comments under the question.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan  he can't comment until he gets his first half-century  :):)

Comment: @SaurabhKumarSingh  i will ask you see the more correct way to do jquery code as posted in other answers.You have redundant jquery code which is not efficient at all.

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing div and you can use $this for which button is clicked.No need to handle click event twice.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').find('.select').click(function() {
    var msg = $(this).html() + "    clicked";
    alert(msg);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <button class="select">one</button>
</div>

<div id="2">
  <button class="select">two</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to handle such things, but while going your specific way/approach; you will need to modify your `JS` code like below:

```
<div id="1">
    <button class="select">one</button>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <button class="select">two</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
 $(function(){
     $('.select').click(function(){
        var parentElement = $(this).closest('div');
        alert ($(parentElement).attr('id'));

    });
});
```

Check this running code example here: https://jsfiddle.net/u2sx44wr/

Answer (score 0):

a good solution for this problem is:

```
$('#1').find('.select').click(function() { ... });
```

with this you can also add the click handler for child elements of the "select" class.